# Group by folder -or a- file

Tags: windows-explorer

Is there a way to group or sort folders : 
[image: context menu scr]

such that the categories :

[image: windows explorer, files grouped by folder scr]

are only "folders" and "files"

Comment: Are you talking about only Libraries? In Windows 7 or 8?

Comment: @Raystafarian I don't think they're relavant.. because 'Libraries' and rest of the folders, and windows 7 and windows 8, are pretty much the same in this context. So I guess if there's a way to make it work in libraries it would do it for me.. and I'm using windows 8.